# Salesforce mobile sdk throwing an error com.android.volley.servererror, basic network perform request 201

Tags: android, salesforce

This is the code to insert a *Case* record into Salesforce via Android mobile but I'm having some problem with the code, below code inserting *Case* record but not sending proper result in response, throwing the following error "com.android.volley.servererror". and BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 201.

```
String objectType = "Case";
Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();
fields.put("Type","Electrical");
fields.put("Subject","Test Subject");
fields.put("Origin","Web");
fields.put("Status","New");
RestRequest restRequest;
try {
    restRequest = RestRequest.getRequestForCreate(getString(R.string.api_version), objectType, fields);
    client.sendAsync(restRequest, new AsyncRequestCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, RestResponse result) {
            try {                   
            (result.isSuccess()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"successfull inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
            } catch(Exception e){}
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Exception exception) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                MainActivity.this.getString(SalesforceSDKManager.getInstance().getSalesforceR().stringGenericError(), exception.toString()
            ),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
} catch (IOException e1) {}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may try to update the Volley library using the latest version. Or change the code in `src/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java`.

```
if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK && statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_NO_CONTENT) {
```

to be

```
if (statusCode &lt; HttpStatus.SC_OK || statusCode &gt; HttpStatus.SC_MULTI_STATUS) {
```

this is a bug in Volley which should treat all 20x response as success